# Redirection to Desired Url

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have a url like:

http://x.x.x.x/~mmi/

which maps to the public_html folder on my site. I have installed cakephp on my site. The default htaccess file for cakephp looks like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to be redirected to:
http://x.x.x.x/~mmi/app/webroot/
instead of :
http://x.x.x.x/app/webroot/~mmi/
which is happening now. How should i modify htaccess file to get this desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Following does the trick:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^~mmi/(.*)$ http://x.x.x.x/~mmi/app/webroot/$1
```